# TortoiseGit... pull remote branch into different local branch

Tags: tortoisegit

I'm working on a local branch and want to merge the latest remote master into this to get it up to date with other changes merged to master from a different branch.

I'm new to git, but TortoiseGit is making it more confusing as it doesn't seem to use exactly the right terminology in the exact same way.

Can I even do this, or do I have to update my entire local repo and then merge my local master -> local branch?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for ?[checkout remote branch under different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043236/pull-remote-branch-into-local-repo-with-different-name/12043264#12043264)

```
git checkout -b myBranchName <repo_name>/<remote's_branch_name>
```