# Pull remote branch into local repo with different name?

Tags: git, github, repository

Alright I did a little bit of research on this but I couldn't find an exact answer, so I have to ask.

I have 2 remotes: origin and repo2.

I'd like to do something like

```
git pull repo2 master
```

But this would pull the master branch of the repo2 into my master. Can I specify a different branch to pull into, for my local branch ?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

```
 git fetch repo2
 git checkout -b myBranchName repo2/master
```

Comment: Note - you have to have run
 `git fetch remote2`
beforehand, if not done yet. Otherwise you may see 
> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'myBranchName' at the same time.

Comment: Note - if you need to push back, use `git push repo2 myBranchName:master` as a simple `git push` will fail

Comment: What if the branch already exists? I want to update code there with the code from repo.

Comment: @Jared Technically a different question, but also easily possible (and actually thats one of the most common use-cases). It slightly depends on what you already did. In most cases it's just `git checkout my_branch && git pull --rebase` (`--rebase` depends on your workflow). If the branch is not already tracking the remote one, you need to execute `git branch --set-upstream my_branch upstream/my_branch` once.

Answer (score 4):

The `git pull` command is a convenience function that does `git fetch` and `git merge`.  If you only want retrieve branches from a new remote without trying to merge it into any working copy branch you can just use `git fetch`.  You can then refer to `git branch -av` to see all the local and remote branches and operate on either remote as you like.